# How many groups are there of order 12?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

All I could think of was the direct products of additive integer groups whereas $gcd(m,n) = 1$, such that $m$, $n$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ .
A hint would be really helpful.

Comment: See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groups+of+order+12.

Comment: You're missing $C_2\times S_3$ for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very short answer, but I will give two links:

- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groups+of+order+12
- http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/group12.pdf, which proves that the five groups of order $12$ listed in the link in the previous bullet are unique up to an isomorphism, by means of semidirect products.

Comment: The link was very helpful, thanks